# C++ stl, functions with no return type

Tags: c++, stl

```
template<typename _Tp1>
operator auto_ptr_ref<_Tp1>() throw()
{ return auto_ptr_ref<_Tp1>(this->release()); }

template<typename _Tp1>
operator auto_ptr<_Tp1>() throw()
{ return auto_ptr<_Tp1>(this->release()); }
```

I found definition of this two methods in stl class auto_ptr.

Can somebody explain me please, how functions other then constructors have no return type ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because they are implicit conversion operators that return `auto_ptr_ref<_Tp1>` and `auto_ptr<_Tp1>` respectively. These themselves serve as *return-type* declarations.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion operators to type `auto_ptr_ref` and `auto_ptr`

n3337 12.3.2/1

> A member function of a class X having no parameters with a name of the form
>
> conversion-function-id:
> operator conversion-type-id
>
> conversion-type-id:
> type-specifier-seq conversion-declaratoropt
>
> conversion-declarator:
> ptr-operator conversion-declaratoropt
>
> specifies a **conversion from X to the type specified by the conversion-type-id**.